# ¿En que debería dividir offset?

Tags: javascript, html, css

mi propósito es que el usuario haga click(como si fuera un onmousedown) en una esquina y lo vaya arrastrando para agrandar un elemento. Tengo un algoritmo que funciona pero no se en que dividir offset para que no salga tan grande el elemento.

Les dejo mi código,

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].addEventListener("mousedown", mousedown); 
function mousedown(){
    document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].addEventListener("mousemove", mousemove); 
    function mousemove(event){
     document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].style.transform= "scale(" + event.offsetX/3 + "," + event.offsetY/3 + ")"; 
    }
}
```

```css
div {
 background: grey;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
 margin-top: 100px;
}
p{
  background: #ccccb3;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="a"><p></p></div>
```

Por otra parte, en esta situación tengo varias posibilidades aparte de hacerlo con offset, puedo hacerlo con screenX, pageX o clientX. ¿Cuál seria mejor usar?

Otra cosa si ven que algo de mi código se puede mejorar les agradecería que me lo dijesen.

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto se puede realizar solo con CSS, usando la propiedad [resize](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_resize.php)

```css
.resize{
 resize:auto;
 background-color: wheat;
 overflow: auto;
 border: 1px solid blue;
 width:100px;
 height:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="resize">
  <div>Algo aca</div>
</div>
```

El estilo del icono se puede cambiar para los navegadores basados en webkit con:

```
::-webkit-resizer
```